# Webpack3 CSS/LESS is not working when imported from React ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am fighting with Webpack to recognize CSS/LESS files without a lot of success.

Here is my Webpack file:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
    entry: ["./src/App.js"],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "app.bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] //, 'less-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader"
                    }
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('app.bundle.css'),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html",
            inject: "body"
        }),

    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./dist",
        filename: "app.bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/",
        stats: {
            colors: true
        }
    },
};
```

I get the following result when I try to import it from my React file:

```
import styles from 'styles/index.css';
```

Error:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'styles/index.css' in '/code/customers/project/map/src'
 @ ./src/App.js 15:13-40
 @ multi ./src/App.js
```

The file is clearly present. Any idea why webpack refuses to include the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prefix with `./` otherwise it is looking for an npm module named `styles`.

```
import styles from './styles/index.css';?
```